# Importing from second array in Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have 2 arrays, 1 is a master (bookArray) and the other an update list (stockBooksArray). I use the loop below to import new data into waster array using a unique record (isbn) that exists in both arrays.

Is there a way to improve the performance of the loop below?

The update array can contain a different count to the master, sometimes more, sometimes less.

```
for i in 0...stockBooksArray.count {


        let StockFiltered = stockBooksArray.filter{$0.isbn == bookArray[i].isbn}

        if StockFiltered.count != 0 {

            bookArray[i].stockAmount = StockFiltered[0].Stock
            bookArray[i].unitCost = StockFiltered[0].Cost
            bookArray[i].dues = StockFiltered[0].dues
            bookArray[i].stockRRP = StockFiltered[0].RRP

            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: Is there a measured performance problem? If not simple beats complex but slightly and not noticeably faster. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- [Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DonKnuth).

Comment: it takes about 5-6 seconds to complete on older devices, 2 seconds on latest (A8). Was just wanting to make it as fast as posable as the sort happens at launch.

Comment: What should happen if `stockBooksArray` has elements that `bookArray` doesn't have? What if `bookArray` has elements that `stockBooksArray` doesn't have? Could simple assignment work?

Comment: @Zaph "This is not premature optimization; it is avoiding gratuitous pessimization." (Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu "C++ Coding Standards")

Comment: Yes and that was not known until the timings were provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Right now you are looping through the bookArray array once for every stockBooksArray object. That's O(N*M) which is pretty bad.

Instead, if you can sort both arrays by ISBN, then you can step through both at the same time, visiting each element only once which would be O(N). Considerably faster, even if you include the time to sort them.

I threw the code below together pretty quick. It assumes that both arrays are sorted by isbn. I think you will find this considerably faster.

```
var j = 0
for book in stockBooksArray {
    while bookArray[j].isbn < book.isbn && j < bookArray.count {
        ++j;
    }
    if j == bookArray.count {
        break
    }
    else if  bookArray[j].isbn == book.isbn {
        bookArray[j].stockAmount = StockFiltered[0].Stock
        bookArray[j].unitCost = StockFiltered[0].Cost
        bookArray[j].dues = StockFiltered[0].dues
        bookArray[j].stockRRP = StockFiltered[0].RRP
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just adding new ones you could get an NSMutableSet of the ISBNs for each, perform a set `minusSet:` operation removing the `bookArray` ISBNs from `stockBooksArray` and then just add the resulting ISBNs to `bookArray`.

Untested concept code, convert to Swift as needed:

```
NSMutableSet *stockBooksSet = NSMutableSet setWithArray:[stockBooksSet valueForKey:@"isbn"];
NSSet *booksSet = NSSet setWithArray:[bookArray valueForKey:@"isbn"];
[stockBooksSet minusSet: booksSet];
for (NSString *isbn in stockBooksSet) {
    // add book with ism to booksSet
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code using Daniel T. method.

```
 bookArray.sort { (lhs, rhs) in return lhs.isbn < rhs.isbn }
    stockBooksArray.sort { (lhs, rhs) in return lhs.isbn < rhs.isbn }

    var j = 0
    for book in stockBooksArray {
        while bookArray[j].isbn < book.isbn && j < bookArray.count {
            ++j
        }
        if j == bookArray.count {
            break
        }
        else if bookArray[j].isbn == book.isbn {
            bookArray[j].stockAmount = book.Stock
            bookArray[j].unitCost = book.Cost
            bookArray[j].dues = book.dues
            bookArray[j].stockRRP = book.RRP
        }
    }
```

From 5-6 seconds on iPad2 to almost instant.

Many thanks,
Anthony